# Bash for loop through array

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm writing a little `bash` script for work. But now I'm stuck. Let me just show you the code and explain:

```
# I have an `array` with names
NAMES=(Skypper Lampart Shepard Ryan Dean Jensen)
```

Now I wanna iterate trough the names

```
for (( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )); do
    COMMAND="sed -i ${i+2}s/.*/${NAMES[${i}]}"
    ${COMMAND} config.txt
done
```

`config.txt` is a file with 2 numbers and names and I just wanna replace the names.

```
1
2
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
Name 5
Name 6
```

My problem is in the `for`-Loop how can I make `$i` + 2? So if I `$i` is 1 it should be 3.

Expected output:

```
1
2
Skypper
Lampart
Shepard
Ryan
Dean
Jensen
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @sat Added my expected output

Comment: I don't understand what is the inline file that sed is going to run the substitution on ?

if you just want the numer $(($i + 2))

Comment: @louigi600 Question is already answered, but ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is good at reading arrays (something you could have easily searched for).

Try something like:

```
for idx in "${!NAMES[@]}"
do
  sed -i "$((idx + 2))s/.*/${NAMES[idx]} $idx/" config.txt
done
```

You will find that placing commands inside variables can also come unstuck unless you know what you are doing, so just use the command as intended :)

You might also need to remember that indexes start at zero and not 1

Comment: The Problem is not the Array but I the solution to my question is this `$((idx + 2))`

Comment: One more problem is, If `idx` is 3 then `3+2 = 5`. It will lead to wrong line in `sed`.

Comment: Yeah in my script I have a `for (( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ))` and the sed is now `sed -i $((${i} + 3))s/.*/${DATA[${i}]}` and it works ty!

Comment: As in example, no need for ${} in either (()) or [].  Another thought is that if you are renaming all the names and know the first 2 lines are all you need from the original file, you could just recreate the file anyway

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want to accomplish (Replace "Name" with a string from NAMES array, problem being index in array starts from 0 and you want to start on the 3rd line) - dirty and quick solution is to add 2 empty strings to beginning of your array and start your loop from the position you want.

Comment: No not the Array index just the number after `-i` because the names in the file start on line number 3.

Comment: Oh, in that case you need to look up bash arithmetic. I think it's ${(i + 2)} or ${((i+2))}, don't have access to bash right now.

Comment: Yeah it is `$((${i} + 3))`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
NAMES=(Skypper Lampart Shepard Ryan Dean Jensen)
line=2  # Need to skip first 2 lines
for name in "${NAMES[@]}"
do
    ((line++))
    sed -i "${line}s/.*/$name/g" config.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something around like this:

```
NAMES=(Skypper Lampart Shepard Ryan Dean Jensen)
for (( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )); do
    b=$(( $i+2 ))
    COMMAND="sed -i $b s/.*/${NAMES[${i}]}"
    echo $COMMAND
#    ${COMMAND} config.txt
done
```

Which gives me something like the following output:

```
# sh test.sh 
sed -i 2 s/.*/Skypper
sed -i 3 s/.*/Lampart
sed -i 4 s/.*/Shepard
sed -i 5 s/.*/Ryan
sed -i 6 s/.*/Dean
sed -i 7 s/.*/Jensen
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late answer... :)

In your code you calling the `sed` n-times. This is inefficient. Therefore me proposing different solution, using `ed` instead of the `sed`. (as in good old times 30 years ago in BSD 2.9 :) ).

For this, approach:

1. first creating commands for the `ed`
2. executing them in one editor invocation

```
# it is good practice not using UPPERCASE variables
# as theycould collide with ENV variables

names=(Skypper Lampart Shepard Ryan Dean Jensen)
file="config.txt"

#create an array of commands for the "ed"
declare -a cmd
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    cmd+=("/Name/s//$name/")
done
cmd+=(w q)

echo "=== [$file before] ==="
cat "$file"

echo "=== [commands for execution ]==="
printf "%s\n" "${cmd[@]}"

#execute the prepared command in the "ed"
printf "%s\n" "${cmd[@]}" | ed -s "$file"

echo "===[ $file after ]==="
cat "$file"
```

output from the above

```
=== [config.txt before] ===
1
2
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
Name 5
Name 6
=== [commands for execution ]===
/Name/s//Skypper/
/Name/s//Lampart/
/Name/s//Shepard/
/Name/s//Ryan/
/Name/s//Dean/
/Name/s//Jensen/
w
q
===[ config.txt after ]===
1
2
Skypper 1
Lampart 2
Shepard 3
Ryan 4
Dean 5
Jensen 6
```

a variant which replaces by the line-numbers

```
names=(Skypper Lampart Shepard Ryan Dean Jensen)
file="config.txt"

#create an array of commands for the "ed"
declare -a cmd
n=3
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    cmd+=("${n}s/.*/$name/")
    let n++
done
cmd+=(w q)

echo "=== [$file before] ==="
cat "$file"

echo "=== [commands for execution ]==="
printf "%s\n" "${cmd[@]}"

#execute the prepared command in the "ed"
printf "%s\n" "${cmd[@]}" | ed -s "$file"

echo "===[ $file after ]==="
cat "$file"
```

output

```
=== [config.txt before] ===
1
2
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
Name 5
Name 6
=== [commands for execution ]===
3s/.*/Skypper/
4s/.*/Lampart/
5s/.*/Shepard/
6s/.*/Ryan/
7s/.*/Dean/
8s/.*/Jensen/
w
q
===[ config.txt after ]===
1
2
Skypper
Lampart
Shepard
Ryan
Dean
Jensen
```

Comment: First of all the Problem is in my case there isn't just the wor `Name` there are already different names :/ And secondly i didn't know `ed`.

Comment: @WasteD i created the answer to your question. In the question the input contains only `Name` strings, without mentioning anything other. It is trivial to modify my answer, but I sill don't know what input do you have...